# Calling same method multiple times with different returns using MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am writing a unit test case where I need to rollback the first payment when the first payment is a success and the second payment fails. The unit test code looks like the following:

1. Process first payment successfully.
2. Process second payment. External system will throw similar transaction fault exception. Parse similar transaction fault exception to get exceptionid and process second transaction again, using the exception id.
3. When the second transaction is actually processed, the system returns a "Payment declined fault exception".
4. The system should then void the first payment.

I have written the unit test for (1). How SO community have pointers on how to take care of part 2, 3, 4?

```
        [TestMethod]    
            public void IfTheSecondPaymentFailsThenTheFirstPaymentShouldBeVoided()
            {
//Arrange        
        var iPaymentMock = new Mock<IPaymentMock>();
                var paymentSpecificationResponse = new PreregisteredAccountSpec();    
                iPaymentMock.Setup(
                        counter => counter.ProcessPayment
                            (
                                It.IsAny<Context>(),
                                It.IsAny<PreregisteredAccountSpec>(),  
                                It.IsAny<Guid>())
                            ).
                        Returns(paymentSpecificationResponse);  
//Act
var twoPaymentProcessor = new TwoPaymentProcessor(iPaymentMock.Object);
twoPaymentProcessor.Submit();

//assert
     iPaymentMock.Verify((
                    counter => counter.ProcessPaymentSpecification
                    (
                        It.IsAny<Context>(),
                        It.IsAny<PreregisteredAccountSpec>(),  
                        It.IsAny<Guid>()
                    )
                ), Times.Once());  
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to use `SetupSequence` rather than `Setup` on the mock.
This allows you to do something like

```
iPaymentMock.SetupSequence(counter => counter.ProcessPayment
    (
         It.IsAny<Context>(),
         It.IsAny<PreregisteredAccountSpec>(),  
         It.IsAny<Guid>())
    )
    .Returns(paymentSpecificationResponse)
    .Throws(new Exception());
```

I might have the specifics of what you're wanting wrong but `SetupSequence` allows you to have multiple returns on a mock, order of calls is important though.

Comment: We cannot use lambdas in SetUpSequence, so not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how one might approach the tests for 2, 3, and 4 but in answer to the general question from the title, one can get different returns from multiple invocations of a mock by using a lamba in the `Returns()` clause.

Say we have the following

```
public interface IPayment
{
    Result ProcessPayment();
}

public class Result
{

    public Result(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
}
```

We can have each call to `ProcessPayment()` return a different value as follows

```
[TestMethod]
public void DifferentResultsOnEachInvocation()
{
    var results = new[] {
                    new Result(1),
                    new Result(2),
                    new Result(3)
                };

    var index = 0;

    var mockPayment = new Mock<IPayment>();
    mockPayment.Setup(mk => mk.ProcessPayment()).Returns(()=>results[index++]);

    var res = mockPayment.Object.ProcessPayment();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, res.Id);

    res = mockPayment.Object.ProcessPayment();
    Assert.AreEqual(2, res.Id);

    res = mockPayment.Object.ProcessPayment();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, res.Id);

}
```

If the setup simply returns `results[index++]` this is crystallized upon setup and each invocation returns the first element of the array. By making it a lamba, it is evaluated each time `ProcessPayment()` is called.

Comment: This is largely opinion but wouldn't `SetupSequence` be easier to both write and read in this case as it removes logic from the test?

Comment: @LukeW For once off tests, `SetupSequence` is simpler but I had started using `Setup` in cases where the sequence of returns was not fixed - I was passing in the array of return values to a common test method - and just got used to using it.

Comment: @AlanT: I think I understand at a high level how I need to setup the MockPayments. I have added more details about the class through which the interaction with the external Payment webservice takes place.